# Homomorphisms $\frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Can someone please show me a concrete example of a group homomorphism
$$ \frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}, $$
if it exists? I apparently cannot find any of it (except for the zero homomorphism).

Comment: You can always map everything to the identity in the codomain.

Comment: @StefanPerko Yes, you are right. I meant "any, except for the zero homomorphism". Now I added it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$Note that in $\Q/\Z$ every element has finite order, as for $a, b \in \Z$, with $b > 0$, we have
$$
b \cdot \frac{a}{b} = a \in \Z.
$$
An element of finite order must be mapped under a homomorphism onto an element of finite order. What are the elements of finite order in $\Q$?